# PHP return array inside a loop

Tags: php, arrays

i am creating a function that loops through records and i want to return the array of items

```
if(!function_exists("TicketAttachments")) {
    function TicketAttachments($update_sequence) {
        global $conn, $pdo_conn;

        $results = array();
        $sql="SELECT * from ticket_updates where ticketnumber = '".$update_sequence."' and type = 'attachment' ";
        $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
        while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
            $results["link"] = 'media/ticket_attachments/'.$result["notes"];
            $results["name"] = $result["notes"];
        }

        return $results;
    }
}
```

i am calling it here:

```
$attachments = TicketAttachments($TicketUpdate["sequence"]);
foreach($attachments as $att) {
    echo $att["name"];
}
```

but this is echoing `h5` whereas name = `55388-20150929124302-screen dump 28092015.docx`

Comment: Stop use deprecated functions!

Comment: `$att["name"];` this line doesn't do anything. did you mean to `echo`?

Comment: check my update - this is how i have it.  i had been testing and forgot to add it back in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think you need to combine the array

```
if(!function_exists("TicketAttachments")) {
    function TicketAttachments($update_sequence) {
        global $conn, $pdo_conn;

        $results = array();
        $sql="SELECT * from ticket_updates where ticketnumber = '".$update_sequence."' and type = 'attachment' ";
        $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
        while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
            $results[] = array(
                "link"=>'media/ticket_attachments/'.$result["notes"],
                "name" => $result["notes"];
            );
        }
        return $results;
    }
}
```